# What is "ɵngcc0" in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular

Where is there a link to read about ɵngcc0?

I mean

```
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: It's just the name of the import. It doesn't have a special meaning.

Comment: You can name it Joe if you want : `import * as Joe from '@angular/core';` and then use it as the variable Joe. It's like `const Joe = require('@angular/core');`

Comment: i am asking about engcc0 methods etc. like it has ɵɵFactoryDef method. where i can read about everything?

Comment: `engcc0` is just the name of [the imported `@angular/core`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents). If there is a `engcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef()` then it should be part of  `@angular/core`.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/CODE_GEN_API.md

Comment: If you want to learn a little bit more about Ivy internals, you can also check [this article](https://blackat.github.io/angular/angular-ivy-introduction/). As author notes, some of it might be wrong - but should give you a fairly decent insight about the basics.

Comment: Where did that sample line of code come from?